# Is it possible to use default paths when I have enabled 'urlFormat'=>'path' in CUrlManager?

Tags: php, yii

Can you explain me this thing? If I use "path" format in CUrlManager, will standart path works?

For example, I have enabled CUrlManager component in my config file:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
'urlFormat'=>'path',
'showScriptName'=>false,
'rules'=>array(
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
),
```

Now I can use path such like this:
    http://example.com/controller/action?param1=value1&param2=value2...

Will it work?:
    http://example.com/index.php?r=controller/action&param1=value1&param2=value2...

I need to use old paths for backward сompatibility with some external programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes its verymuch possible

try this

```
     print Yii::app()->request->getParam("param2");exit;
```

If any problem let me know

Comment: It works for me but I'm not sure is it correct behaviour of Yii or not? That therefore I asked.

Comment: Yes its pretty correct, and one benefit of that is you never got any warning/exception like $_POST['param1'] if you uses getParam. :)

Answer (score 0):

No it won't work by default, but there are some dirty hacks possible to make old paths continue to work usually by modifying the index.php file , something like as mentioned [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/15649-adding-new-rules-in-url-manager-and-keep-old-links-working/page__view__findpost__p__7)